# PHPCAS in Limesurvey

Tags: cas, limesurvey, phpcas

I have some trouble in PHPcas connect with limesurvey

If I use [limesurvey-cas](https://github.com/univlorraine/limesurvey-cas), I can't logout and login if use it plugin

and if I use this version https://github.com/goyome/LimeSurvey, Can't create a user auto

What should I do if I use PHPCAS to login. If you have a 
Completed version for PHPCAS in limesurvey, That's very much.

What I want like this: http://survey.sjtu.edu.cn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you add more informations to help to find the problem ?
You could add debug informations by adding, in your "config.php" :
+       'debug'=>1,

In some cases, it could failed to call "CAS.php"

Comment: A new version has been released on github. The problem with CAS.php was corrected. Try it and let us know...